# Using PHP Simple Dom Parser to extract content from Indeed and Put it in a Table

Tags: php, parsing, dom, foreach

I am trying to parse Indeed using PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser.
I am new to PHP. 
I need help to take the content from Indeed and represent it as a table.

So in short I need it in the following way.

Table:

```
Company Name | Job Title | job Description | Date of posting 
------------------------------------------------------------
IBM          | Developer | developer at US | 12/22/2014
```

---

Code:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
// Create DOM from URL or file

$str = '';

// Find all images 
$html = file_get_html('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q="IBM"&l=');
foreach($html->find('div[data-tn-component=organicJob]') as $jobtitle) 
    $str =$str . $jobtitle->innertext . '<br>';
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Use [the API](https://www.indeed.com/publisher) instead of trying to scrape the site.

Comment: i am not comfortable with the API since it doesnt give the job description

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I have reached. It now creates a table.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file


$rowData = array();
echo '<table style=width:100%><tr>'; 
    echo '<th>Job title</th><th>location</th><th>company</th></tr>'; 
$html = file_get_html('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=IBM&l=');

foreach ($html->find('div[data-tn-component=organicJob]') as $item){

    echo '<tr><td>' . $item->children(0)->plaintext . "</td>";

    foreach ($item->find('span[itemprop=jobLocation]') as $col2){


      echo '<td>' . $col2 . "</td>";
    }
    foreach ($item->find('span[class=company]') as $col){
      echo '<td>' . $col . "</td>";
    }

echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```